# Where to find Population Density (shp. or grid) for Europe?

Tags: data, density, population, europe, demography

Does anybody know where to download shp. or grid file on European population density (inhabitants/ sq.km)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever looked at all the data provided by the European Union and its member states?

Such as [eurostat](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Main_Page) or [inspire geoportal](http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/)?

Within eurostat you will find a page on [population density](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Population_statistics_at_regional_level#Population_density) which will help you in your quest...but you will likely have to do some manipulation bringing together several products to create what you are looking for. Like download the admin areas dataset then append the population data to that dataset

Answer (score -1):

You can find a fine grained dataset on the European Environment Agency website : http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/population-density-disaggregated-with-corine-land-cover-2000-2

It combines population data per commune with CORINE Land Cover to get a 1 ha resolution grid.